# Fixed div over my window scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

My Problem is that I have fixed div at the bottom on my page with disclaimer and so on.

This DIV is overlapping the vertical scrollbar so I have deleted the overflow from the parent element.

Now that is working but I need the overflow for the parent element to see the further content when scrolling the page.

Can someone help me?

Comment: add `z-index` for your fixed div.

Comment: @Roi http://jsfiddle.net/19csm3xL/ - but my problem is not visible there

Comment: have u tried overflow-x:hidden; in body tag

Comment: @aashi no thats not working. I also tried it with overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: auto

Comment: ok, so try 1 more thing..use custom scroll(nicescroll). Do overflow:hidden for body.. n use custom scroll for your content part

I have applied this approach, when i have to keep header fixed n content scrollable'

Comment: @Snickbrack $(window).resize(function(){  
  var a3 = $(window).height();
  var w2=a2-50;
  $(".dashboard-content").css({'height':+w2+'px'});  
 });

You can calculate height my this code

Comment: @aashi hmm, the height is not the problem in this case. I have my disclaimer fixed at the bottom of the window like you can see in my  jsfiddle example. I just want to prevent the fixed div to not overflow my scrollbar. And I can't remove the overflow: auto; from my parent element cause I need the content flow down on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/19csm3xL/1/)

```
#scrollable
{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div.bottom
{
    background-color: #fa0000;
    position:  fixed;
    bottom: 0%;

    /*height: 10%;*/
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    z-index:9999;
}

div.test
{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top : 10px;
    background: #000000;
    height: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I see the z-index that you have add but that don't fix my problem cause the div wont [@#!%$§] go behind the [§%@!$] scrollbar.

Comment: I didn't get that part, Had the same problem but removing the overflow (also, placing it to auto) and an auto z-index helped) why don't you try this, if that doesn't help, just remove the z-index too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the height of your container. The height should be such that it will just be enough for the disclaimer div to be visible. Then give the overflow:auto to the container. This will take care of scrolling and overlapping.

THe height can be calculated depending on the DOM structure of your page. But Please give proper height.

The concept of overflow is really simple, when your content "oveflows" a scrollbar appears if u have given overflow attribute. In your case, the overflow is occuring , but since the available height is more, it is going beyond your disclaimer div. Just make it less so that your disclaimer div and container div do not overlap. And you should be fine

If you had posted the code and page structure, it would have been simpler to explain.

Comment: the height is no the problem in this case. I literally need the container to be this large because in there is a lot of content.